# how to get response code in android

Tags: android

i am using ksoap to get connected with my web services i got response code "000" as login successful on my logcat now my question is that how to handle that response code so that user can go to next page if possible please provide code..

Comment: Your best bet on SO is to try what your asking first and post some type of example of what your trying. That way the community is helping you as opposed to writing your code. Also, searching, I am sure will reveal plenty of examples. See below as well for an example of conditional logic that will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some conditional logic to programmatically decide what to do. If the user gets passed with a successful login, I would think you would want to send them to the main app screen??

```
if (ResponseCode == "000"){
startActivity (Intent) // where you want the user to go.
}
Else If (ResponseCode == "whateverelse"){
//Restart Login screen
}
Else {
//Your locked out or whatever other scenario you may have.
}
```

Something like the above will work. THere may also be additional Android login functional;ity, but I just set a boolean and pass it along with the user so I can check his login status when I may beed to.

Comment: you know @apesa am doing in the same way but for login success it is working and when am putting 001 it is not working am not able to find out what mistake am doing...

Comment: yes that is correct but not working for response code "001" what is wrong